# ¿ Por que sale una linea de texto sobre las funciones en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: funciones, visual-studio-2017

Hola desde hace días en Visual Studio Code me sale un texto sobre las funciones de mi código: `Complexity is 11 You must be kidding.` (lo marco con flecha verde en la imagen)

El numero cambia dependiendo de la función.

También sale un cuadrado de color tras la llave de la función (lo marco con flecha azul)

Al pinchar en el texto, que no cuenta como linea de código, aparece varias lineas en la parte de arriba del editor.

***¿Que función o significado tiene esto?***

Hace días instale una extensión de Node.js, pero ahora no aparece para decirles cual es y quiza tenga que ver.

Si me dieran una idea de que es o donde buscar, revise tutoriales de Microsoft y no encuentro nada.

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez este enlace te sriva https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Como-instalar-y-desinstalar-extensiones-en-Visual-Studio-Code.aspx

Comment: Revisa las extensiones que tienes instalado en tu vscode, debes tener alguna que esta causando que te muestre este texto helper para javascript, solo basta con desinstalarlo.

Comment: Ya, pero no se que significan los mensajes, por lo que no se que extensión eliminar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dice @alanfcm en parte es por **"CodeMetrics"**, pero debe ser una dependencia de **VS Code for Node.js**.
Si te molesta mucho, eliminandolo desaparecerá todo, los comentarios y los cuadros de colores.
 **"CodeMetrics"**, no podrás al ser una dependencia. 
Espero haber ayudado.

> EDITO:
>   Si solo modificas `editor.codelens: false` es cuando solo desaparece el comentario, **CodeMetrics** no podrás eliminarlo.

Comment: Funciono eliminando VS Code for Node.js

Answer (score 2):

Puedes desactivar los mensajes en el archivo settings.json.  Necesitas cambiar el siguiente setting:

```
"editor.codeLens": false,
```

Puedes encontrar los settings en:

> File > Preferences > Settings

Comment: Gracias, pero ¿ que significan esos mensajes.?

Comment: Es un poco complicado, en ingles se llama "Cyclomatic complexity".  Puedes leer acerca de ello aqui:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity

Comment: Por cierto, la extension que probablemente instalaste es "CodeMetrics".  Documentacion aqui: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-codemetrics